# Difficulty printing all 6 of my matlab figures to PDF (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I've got a script I've been working on that publishes figures I create into power point, consecutively. Each figure that is created is assigned a figure handle in the previous script. However, when I try to print each figure into a pdf, it will only return a copy of the PDF with my final figure handle (FH6). How can i get this script to print each figure, FH1-FH6, into a single pdf or their own separate pdfs. Thank you for your time

Here is an example of what i have:

```
close all
clear
get_mlo_data
import mlreportgen.ppt.*;

slidesFile = 'mySlides_v1.pptx';
delete(slidesFile)
slides = Presentation(slidesFile);

slide1 = add(slides,'Title Slide');
replace(slide1,'Title','Research Presentation');
replace(slide1,'Subtitle','Author');

insertmyimage(fh1,slides,'CO2 Trends')
insertmyimage(fh2,slides,'Keeling Curve')
insertmyimage(fh3,slides,'Interpolated Vs Trend')
insertmyimage(fh4,slides,'DOTS')
insertmyimage(fh5,slides,'Seasonal')
insertmyimage(fh6,slides,'Keeling Spiral')

please_god = get(groot, 'Children');
print('please_god','-dpdf')

close(slides);

function insertmyimage(FigureHandle,slides,FigureTitle)
import mlreportgen.ppt.*;
tempimgname = ['WayneImage' num2str(numel(slides.Children)+1) '.png'];
saveas(FigureHandle,tempimgname);
tempplot = Picture(tempimgname);
pictureSlide = add(slides,'Title and Content');
replace(pictureSlide,'Title',FigureTitle);
replace(pictureSlide,'Content',tempplot)
end
```